# Les vers de terre se trouvent sous la terre ou sous-sol?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire

Je vais essayer de poser la question en français.

Je suis en train d'écrire quelques phrases sur les oiseaux chanteurs. Ils mangent des vers de terre.

Alors, je ne sais pas comment dire.

> Le ver de terre que l'oiseau a mangé se trouvait sous la terre.
>
> Le ver de terre que l'oiseau a mangé se trouvait sous-sol.

Je ne comprends pas la différence entres ces deux phrases que j'ai formulé.

Je pense que ça vaut la peine de demander de l'aide avant d'écrire des bêtises.

Comment: Le ver que l'oiseau a mangé se trouvait dans l'oiseau, c'est pas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pour ce qui est du choix entre **sous la terre** et **sous-sol**, il suffit juste de comprendre le sens de ces deux mots.

Le sous-sol se traduit en anglais par *subsoil*, il définit dans la plupart des cas une partie de bâtiment qui est en-dessous du rez-de-chaussée ou en géologie la croute terrestre sous le sol.
Notez qu'il faut écrire **au** sous-sol :

> Je vais **au** sous-sol prendre mes affaires.

Pour ce qui est de la phrase *sous la terre*, on peut la traduire par *underground*. Elle est souvent utilisée pour parler de quelque chose de naturel, dans votre exemple des oiseaux cela fonctionne à merveille.

> On trouve parfois des trésors enfouis sous la terre.

La phrase correcte est-donc :

> Le ver de terre que l'oiseau a mangé se trouvait sous la terre.

*If you have any question or if you need help translating what I wrote tell me*

Comment: Désolée mais sous-sol n'est pas sub-soil, sauf dans les domaines assez techniques géologiques comme vous l'avez dit. Un parking sous-sol: underground parking. Le sous-sol du bâtiment: the basement of the building. Mais des vers sous la terre, se dit: worms are in or under the ground, in the earth.

Answer (score 3):

*Sous la terre* n'est pas correct, on n'utilise pas cette formulation. On ne soulève pas la terre, on la creuse.
On dit *dans la terre*, c'est là que vivent les asticots. On dit sous une pierre sous un rocher, là aussi on peut trouver des vers de terre.
Par contre quand on dit *sous-terre* cela correspond à n'importe quelle distance depuis la surface.

Pour parler du niveau de construction en dessous du rez-de-chaussée qui lui est au niveau du sol, on dit *sous-sol*.

Comment: Juste pour pinailler, un asticot n'est pas un ver de terre: c'est une larve de mouche.

Comment: @mouviciel bien vu. Cela dit on peut quand même les trouver dans la terre avant qu'elles se transforment en mouche.